# can't convert qt designer .ui to .py

Tags: python, pyqt, discord.py, designer, fb.ui

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOMtJ.png)
I don't understand

I'm try to making design for calculator app desktop by QtDesigner but I can't got python code for my design to start make functions to the Button's and start my first App

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), also avoid unnecessary/irrelevant comments.